# Android BottomNavigationView OnNavigationItemSelectedListener Code Not Running

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I am working on an app to provide students with schedules, etc. for a school. I am trying to implement the BottomNavigationView in place of independent buttons at the bottom of each tab. I have completed extensive research to find out how to use the BottomNavigationView, and successfully created several test apps. However, I have thus far been unable to get the BottomNavigationView to work when implemented into previously written code. The view itself shows up, but the OnNavigationItemSelectedListener code is not running. Note: The amount of previously written code already in the app means that the best way (I think) to use the BottomNavigationView in this app is to switch to a different java class when one of the items in the BottomNavigationView is selected, and to have identical BottomNavigationViews in each of the four activities that I currently have.

The onCreate of the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    findToday();
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomnavschedule);
    navigation.bringToFront();
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.schedule_tab:
                    return true;
                case R.id.barcode_tab:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), barcodeActivity.class));
                    return true;
                case R.id.contacts_tab:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), friendActivity.class));
                    return true;
                case R.id.other_tab:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), otherActivity.class));
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    new refreshSchedule().execute();
```

and the XML in activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.fuady.ssa_app_redo1.MainActivity"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/appbg4">

    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="530dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.fuady.ssa_app_redo1.MainActivity">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/todayButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/dayScroller"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:onClick="todayButtonFunction"
            android:text="Today"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previousDayButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/dayScroller"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/todayButton"
            android:onClick="previousDay"
            android:text="Previous Day"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextDayButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/dayScroller"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/todayButton"
            android:onClick="nextDay"
            android:text="Next Day"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/todayButton"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button19"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button19"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="editSchedule"
            android:src="@drawable/editicon" />


        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/dayScroller"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomnavschedule"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_resource" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My menu file for the BottomNavigationView (named bottomnavresource):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/schedule_tab"
        android:title="Schedule"
        android:icon="@drawable/shedules"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/barcode_tab"
        android:title="Barcode"
        android:icon="@drawable/barcodeicon"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/contacts_tab"
        android:title="Contacts"
        android:icon="@drawable/friend"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/other_tab"
        android:title="More"
        android:icon="@drawable/other"
        />
</menu>
```

I have not yet attempted to implement the BottomNavigationView into any of the other tabs because it does not work in this tab. I have also created another program with nearly identical BottomNavigationView code (none of the other code specifically for this app) as a test, and it worked perfectly. I have changed many things around many times, and still, when any tab on the BottomNavigationView is clicked, the tab becomes selected but the activity does not switch.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I am not sure. Are you missing the break statement in switch case ?

Comment: The return true should act as a break statement.